# Characterization of injective linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Seeing other questions here, I realized this is a known fact:

> A linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ is injective
>   iff there is $\alpha\gt 0$ such that $\|T(x)\|\ge \alpha\|T(x)\|$ for
>   all $x$.

I'm trying to prove it, I don't know if this can help but what I know is there is a $\beta\gt 0$ such that $\|T(x)\|\le \beta\|T(x)\|$ for all $x$, for every linear transformation $T$.

How can we prove this? why this is never taught in regular linear algebra classes?

There is a similar characterization to surjective linear transformations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $T$ restriced to the unit sphere $S$ in $\Bbb R^n$.  Since $T$ is linear and acts on the finite dimensional space $\Bbb R^n$, $T$ is continuous, so $T$ restricted to $S$ is a continuous function on $S$.  $S$ being compact, $T$ attains its minimum value at some $z \in S$.  $Tz \ne 0$ since $T$ is injective, so $\Vert Tz \Vert = \alpha > 0$.  It follows that for any $y \in S$, $\Vert Ty \Vert \ge \alpha$.  Now use linearity:  if $0 \ne x \in \Bbb R^n$, then $x / \Vert x \Vert \in S$, so $\Vert T(x/ \Vert x \Vert) \Vert \ge \alpha$, whence $\Vert T(x) \Vert \ge \alpha \Vert x \Vert$.  Going the other way is easier, since $\Vert T(x) \Vert \ge \alpha \Vert x \Vert$ implies $T(x) \ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$.  ***QED.***

***Note:***  We tacitly used $\Vert T(x) \Vert \le \beta \Vert x \Vert$ in the (equivalent) assertion that $T$ is continuous.  The title factoid *is* in fact taught sometimes, somewhere.  A similar result for surjective $T$ is problematic, since we might lose $\alpha > 0$, which depends on injectivity.   A careful analysis might reveal a useful formulation, however.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Great solution, very clean, thank you very much!

Comment: The only thing I didn't understand was this phrase: "We tacitly used $\Vert T(x) \Vert \le \beta \Vert x \Vert$ in the (equivalent) assertion that $T$ is continuous." Maybe because of bad my english, I didn't understand what you meant, thanks again!

Comment: "Tacitly" means "without making explicit mention"; I think it's from the Latin for "silent" or something.  Does that clarify?

Comment: I know, what I didn't understand is what you meant exactly, do you mean we can use $\|T(x)\|\le \beta \|x\|$ to prove $T$ is continuous?

Comment: In a word, yes.  $\Vert T(x) \Vert \le \beta \Vert x \Vert$ is equivalent to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuity for linear $T$.  Also, in finite dinensions, *every*´linear $T$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you again for the clarification.

Comment: Hey, no problemo, senor!  Thanks for the kind words and of course, the "acceptance"!  Cheers!